# Dynamic Field Name in @wire

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am building a custom toast component that I want to pass in different field values into. This could be on Account/Case/Asset anything really. Below is the code I have written. The issue is trying to get

1. the fields
2. the data from the fields

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

JS code:

```
@api title;
@api variant;
@api mode;
@api fieldName;
variantOptions = [
    { label: 'error', value: 'error' },
    { label: 'warning', value: 'warning' },
    { label: 'success', value: 'success' },
    { label: 'info', value: 'info' },
];

@wire(getRecord, {
    recordId: '$recordId',
    fields: [this.fieldName],
}) wireuser({
    error,
    data
}) {
    if (error) {
       this.error = error ; 
    } else if (data) {
        this.message = data.fields.$fieldName.value;
        this.showNotification();
    }
}
```

XML Code:

````
<targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordPage">
            <property name="title" type="String" default=""></property>
            <property name="fieldName" type="String" default=""></property>
            <property name="variant" type="String" datasource="error, warning, success, info"></property>
            <property name="mode" type="String" datasource="dismissable, pester, sticky"></property>
        </targetConfig>
</targetConfigs>```
````

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**PROBLEM:**

`data.fields.$fieldName.value` will not work as you will not have any field with api name `$fieldName`.

**UNDERSTANDING:**

You can use refer to [Object Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer):

Consider below object:

```
var object = {
  foo: 'bar',
  age: 42,
  baz: {myProp: 12}
}
```

You can get values either by *DOT notation* or *square brackets* as below:

```
object.foo; // "bar"
object['age']; // 42

object.foo = 'baz';
```

**SOLUTION:**

You can use

```
this.message = data.fields[this.fieldName].value;
```